# Gremlin.NET API: Can we create multiple vertices with single submit query using gremlin.NET

Tags: c#

I'm using `gremlin.net` `API` to add **vertices** to a graph database by submitting a query like below...

`"g.addV('V1').property('name','N1')";`

To insert multiple **vertices**, I'm submitting queries multiple times which is causing `429 error`.

Is there a way we can create multiple **vertices** with a single query submission?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060203/how-to-add-vertices-to-gremlin-server-in-a-batch-from-gremlin-net) post links to someone trying to achieve the same as you, unfortunately it requires porting a Java solution to C# though.

Answer (score 0):

Using GraphBulkExecutor for .net fixed performance issue related to inserting large data of vertices and edges to graph db
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-graph-dotnet